# List name of columns with numeric values, it didn't work

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, data-science

I wanted a list of columns with numeric values I tried the code in the image but it didn't work, anybody knows why? is there another way to do it? thankyou

[image]

Comment: What image? What code? What have you tried to resolve it?

Comment: I'm sorry, image didn't load

Comment: Ahh cool, the image arrived. Now what? You want us to write your code? You do realize you provide an awfully little amount of information.

Comment: First you have the list of columns, then the code trying to filter columns and list them, then the result, the Object columns are still there

Comment: I'm learning and I tried to do it by myself, if you could tell me the error or guide me, it would be nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.select_dtypes()` gives you a filtered out dataset with only numeric columns and with `.columns` you get a list of the columns like this:

```
employee_df.select_dtypes(include=['int', 'float']).columns
```